# save_post not called in plugin / custom field still saving overwriting metaboxes

Tags: plugin-development, metabox, save-post

I have a plugin that writes metaboxes to certain pages.  It writes the metaboxes fine and everything works as should...until I save.  The save_post is not getting called, and I can't figure out why.  Here is the code in my __Construct

```
class Plg_Admin_Meta {

public static function start() {
 return new self();
} 

public function __construct() {
  $this->plugin_url = WP_CONTENT_URL . '/plugins/' . basename(dirname(__FILE__));
  $this->plugin_dir = dirname(__FILE__);

  add_action('admin_init', array($this, '_admin_init'));  
  add_action('save_post', array($this, '_save_post'), 99);
}
```

The metaboxes are made from custom fields, and if I edit a custom field text area it saves fine, but I want it to save the data entered from the metabox instead.  For whatever reason the save_post will not fire.  I tried putting a die(var_dump($_POST)) at the start of my _save_post function and it isn't even firing.

Here is my _save_post function

```
public function _save_post($post_id) {
  //die(dump_var($_POST));
  update_post_meta($post_id, 'content__service_overviews', "test2");
  // Post meta isn't sent for autosaves
  if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
    return;
  }
}

Plg_Admin_Meta::start();
```

As you can see I am just manually trying to update a field right now, but the function isn't even getting called.

EDIT: Requested entire class:

```
  class Plg_Admin_Meta {

    public static function start() {
     return new self();
    } 

    public function __construct() {
      $this->plugin_url = WP_CONTENT_URL . '/plugins/' . basename(dirname(__FILE__));
      $this->plugin_dir = dirname(__FILE__);
      $this->prefix = 'content__';
      $this->page_fields = array(
        'site' => array(
          'textarea:slideshow',
          'text:address',
          'text:phone',
          'text:fax',
          'text:twitter_link',
          'text:weather_link',
          'text:meta_description',
          'text:meta_keywords',
          'text:google_analytics_account_number',
          'text:google_site_verification_code'
        ),
        'home' => array(
          'textarea:about_enernex',
          'textarea:introducing_utility_stats',
          'textarea:recent_content',
          'textarea:workshop_button'
        ),
        'about' => array(
          'textarea:what_we_do_photo',
          'textarea:what_we_do',
          'textarea:our_mission_photo',
          'textarea:our_mission',
          'textarea:get_to_know_us_photo',
          'textarea:get_to_know_us_principals',
          'textarea:get_to_know_us_staff'
        ),
        'careers' => array(
          'textarea:why_enernex_photo',
          'textarea:why_enernex',
          'textarea:support_our_mission_photo',
          'textarea:support_our_mission',
          'textarea:the_innovation_valley_photo',
          'textarea:the_innovation_valley_our_location'
        ),
        'contact' => array(
          'textarea:photo',
          'textarea:contact_information',
          'textarea:map_image',
          'textarea:directions'
        ),
        'employees' => array(
          'text:title',
          'textarea:text',
          'textarea:photo'
        ),
        'support' => array(
          'textarea:announcing_utility_stats',
          'textarea:faq',
          'textarea:utility_ownership_key',
          'textarea:support'
        ),
        'newsroom' => array(
          'textarea:service_overviews',
          'textarea:media_contacts',
          'textarea:industry_resources_and_related_links'
        ),
        'services' => array(
          'textarea:main_text',
          'textarea:power_systems_consulting_photo',
          'textarea:smart_grid_engineering_photo',
          'textarea:smart_grid_labs_photo',
          'textarea:workshops_photo'
        ),
        'iec-workshop' => array(
          'textarea:first_photo',
          'textarea:course_overview',
          'textarea:topics_covered',
          'textarea:our_instructors',
          'textarea:workshop_dates',
          'textarea:who_should_attend',
          'textarea:key_benefits',
          'textarea:schedule_location_and_cost',
          'textarea:second_photo',
          'textarea:location'
        ),
        'cyber-security' => array(
          'textarea:meet_the_team',
          'text:media_kit_download_link'
        )
      );

      $this->post_fields = array(
        'news' => array(
          'textarea:overview',
          'textarea:story'
        ),
        'press' => array(
          'textarea:overview',
          'textarea:story'
        ),
        'whitepapers' => array(
          'textarea:overview',
          'textarea:uploads'
        ),
        'areas' => array(
          'textarea:overview',
          'textarea:uploads',
          'textarea:projects'
        ),
        'links' => array(
          'text:URL'
        ),
        'jobs' => array(
          'textarea:basic_function',
          'textarea:education_and_experience',
          'textarea:skills',
          'textarea:duties_and_responsibilities',
          'textarea:contact_information',
          'textarea:notes'
        ),
        'employees' => array(
          'text:position',
          'text:department',
          'text:year_joined',
          'text:power_industry_years',
          'text:education',
          'text:expertise',
          'text:phone',
          'text:email_address',
          'textarea:biography',
          'textarea:headshot'
        ),
        'blog' => array(
          'textarea:author',
          'textarea:content'
        ),
        'announcements' => array(
          'text:link_to_announcement',
          'textarea:content'
        )
      );



      add_action('admin_init', array($this, '_admin_init'));  
      add_action('save_post', array($this, '_save_post'), 99, 2);   



    }


    public function _admin_init() {

      $post_id = isset($_REQUEST['post']) ? $_REQUEST['post'] : false;
      if ($post_id) {

        $content = get_post($post_id);
        $slug = $content->post_name;
        $post_type = $content->post_type;

        if (isset($post_type)) {

          switch($post_type) {

            case 'page':
              $this->_create_metaboxes('page', $this->page_fields[$slug]);
            break;

            case 'post':
              $category = get_the_category($post_id);
              $slug = $category[0]->slug;
              $this->_create_metaboxes('post', $this->post_fields[$slug]);
            break;

          }

        }

      }

    }

    public function _create_metabox_content($post, $metabox) {

      $post_id = $post->ID;   
      $meta_key = $metabox['args']['meta_key'];
      $meta_value = get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, true);

      switch ($metabox['args']['type']) {

        case 'text':

          ?>

          <input type="text" name="<?php echo $meta_key; ?>" value="<?php echo $meta_value; ?>" style="font-family:'Georgia', 'Times New Roman', 'Bistream Charter', 'Times', 'serif';font-size: 13px; line-height: 19px; color: #333; width: 100%;" />

          <?php

        break;

        case 'textarea':

          wp_editor( 
            $meta_value,
            $meta_key,
            array(
              'textarea_name' => $meta_key,
              'textarea_rows' => 4,
              'tinymce' => array(
                'content_css' => $this->plugin_url . '/tinymce.css'
              )
            )        
          );     

        break;

      }

    }

    public function _create_metaboxes($post_type, $fields_array) {

      if (!empty($fields_array)) {

          wp_enqueue_style('admin', $this->plugin_url . '/admin.css');

            foreach ($fields_array as $field) {

              $tokens = explode(':', $field);
              $type = $tokens[0];
              $meta_key = $this->prefix . $tokens[1];
              $id = 'metabox_' . $tokens[1];
              $title = ucwords(preg_replace('/\_/', ' ', $tokens[1]));            

              add_meta_box(
                $id,
                $title,
                array($this, '_create_metabox_content'),
                $post_type,
                'normal',
                'high',
                array(
                  'meta_key' => $meta_key,
                  'type' => $type
                )                  
              );

            }

      }

    }  

    public function _save_post($post_id) {

    //die(var_dump($_POST));
    // Post meta isn't sent for autosaves
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
      return;
    }

    update_post_meta($post_id, 'content__service_overviews', "test2");


      if (isset($_REQUEST['post_ID'])) {


          foreach ($_REQUEST as $meta_key => $meta_value) {
            if (strstr($meta_key, $this->prefix)) {

            //update_post_meta(intval($_REQUEST['post_ID']), meta_key, meta_value);

            }

          }


      }

    }


  }


  Plg_Admin_Meta::start();
```

Comment: can you post the entire class? Your static function seems a little odd/redundant

Comment: @TomJNowell I posted the entire class, thanks for taking the time to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out the problem was in the database.  If I deleted the page, then re-created it then it functioned as it should.  I couldn't narrow down what exactly was wrong with the data, but something was.

That page did have a lot of revisions, not that it should matter?

Comment: I came across this same issue on a project three months ago, I had to put it down and just came back to it. Thankfully I found this post. After deleting the page and recreating it, I was able to save to it again. Makes no sense.